# OpenShift Custom Cartridge and NPM

Tags: nginx, npm, openshift

I am working with a [community-developed OpenShift cartridge](https://github.com/gsterjov/openshift-nginx-cartridge) for nginx. The cartridge's build script (without any modifications) works well; it starts the nginx server with the configuration file that I provide it. However, I am trying to modify the build script so that it first changes directory into my OpenShift repository, runs `npm install` and then `grunt build` to build an Angular application that I have created.

When I do this, I continuously get the error `EACCES, mkdir '/var/lib/openshift/xxxxxxxxxx/.npm'` when the script gets to `npm install`. Some [OpenShift forum posts](https://www.openshift.com/forums/openshift/php-53-cartridge-npm-not-working-quickfix) have attempted to solve the issue, but it appears as though a different solution is required (at least in my case).

Thus, I am interested in whether or not it is possible to use npm in this way, or if I need to create a cartridge that does all of this myself.

Comment: if you have a second could you read over a [similar issue](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26830194/npm-install-on-openshift-jenkins-gear) I am having with Jenkins and NPM on OpenShift? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since we do not typically have the access required to create `~/.npm`, we have to find ways of moving the npm cache (normally `~/.npm`) and the npm user configuration (normally `~/.npmrc`) to accessible folders to get things going. The following information comes partially from a [bug report](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1147762) that I submitted to Redhat on this matter.

We must begin by creating an environmental variable to [control the location of .npmrc](https://www.npmjs.org/doc/misc/npm-config.html). I created a file (with shell access to my application) called `.env` in `$OPENSHIFT_DATA_DIR`. Within this file, I have placed:

```
export NPM_CONFIG_USERCONFIG=$OPENSHIFT_HOMEDIR/app-root/build-dependencies/.npmrc
```

This moves the `.npmrc` directory to a place where we have the privileges to read/write. Naturally, I have to also create the directory `.npmrc` in `$OPENSHIFT_HOMEDIR/app-root/build-dependencies/`. Then, in my pre-start webhook/early in my build script, I have placed:

```
touch $OPENSHIFT_DATA_DIR/.env
```

This ensures that the environmental variable that configures the location of `.npmrc` will be accessible each time we deploy/build. Now we can move the location of the npm cache. Start by running `touch` on the `.env` file manually, and create the `.npm` directory in `$OPENSHIFT_HOMEDIR/app-root/build-dependencies/`. Run the following to complete the reconfiguration:

```
npm config set cache $OPENSHIFT_HOMEDIR/app-root/build-dependencies/.npm
```

NPM should now be accessible each time we deploy, even if we are not using the NodeJS cartridge. The above directory choices may be changed as desired.

Answer (score 0):

You do not have write access to the ~/.npm directory in your gear.  You might try reviewing how the native node.js cartridge is setup (https://github.com/openshift/origin-server/tree/master/cartridges/openshift-origin-cartridge-nodejs) and see if you can apply it to your custom cartridge.

Comment: I was looking at this, but I'm a bit confused as to how the installation script has permission to do things such as `touch "$OPENSHIFT_HOMEDIR"/.npmrc`. I do not have permission to do this either.

Comment: Cartridges and their scripts have access there, but you don't when you ssh in, and your .openshift/action_hooks don't.

Comment: With a moderate amount of reconfiguration, it appears as though we can get around this issue (at least for npm). Please see my answer below