# Install Node packages over Python gear in Openshift

Tags: python, node.js, openshift, npm-install

I have set up a Django application on the [RedHat Openshift](https://hub.openshift.com/quickstarts/103-python-3-3) server with a single Python3.3 gear. For the front-end part of the application I need several tools: [less](https://www.npmjs.com/package/less), [typescript](https://www.npmjs.com/package/typescript), [google-closure-compiler](https://www.npmjs.com/package/google-closure-compiler), which should be installed with the `npm install <package>` command.

Unfortunately it doesn't seem to be possible, since execution of this command in the Openshift SSH console yields a permission error:

```
npm ERR! Error: EACCES, mkdir '/var/lib/openshift/572240982d5271a20c0000e2/.npm'
npm ERR!  { [Error: EACCES, mkdir '/var/lib/openshift/572240982d5271a20c0000e2/.npm']
npm ERR!   errno: 3,
npm ERR!   code: 'EACCES',
npm ERR!   path: '/var/lib/openshift/572240982d5271a20c0000e2/.npm' }
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Please try running this command again as root/Administrator.
```

Fortunately I can install the [google-closure-compiler](https://developers.google.com/closure/compiler/) by just downloading the compiled Java script, but for others there is no alternative installation method documented.

Is it possible to somehow install these packages for a Python app in Openshift so that the `lessc` and `tsc` compilers can be executed on the server during the build process?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to a very similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26086325/openshift-custom-cartridge-and-npm/26150783#26150783) that was asked before, I've figured out how to do this, although potentially not in the most optimal way. The procedure that worked for me is the following:

1. Connect to your app via SSH and set the environment variable pointing to the location with dependencies:
   `export DEPENDENCY_BASE="$OPENSHIFT_HOMEDIR/app-root/dependencies"`
2. Install the latest/desired version of `node.js` under `$DEPENDENCY_BASE/node` by downloading the Linux binary from the [official web site](https://nodejs.org/en/download/), and extracting it:
   `cd $DEPENDENCY_BASE; wget https://nodejs.org/dist/v4.4.3/node-v4.4.3-linux-x64.tar.xz; tar -xf node-v4.4.3-linux-x64.tar.xz; mv node-v4.4.3-linux-x64 node; rm node-v4.4.3-linux-x64.tar.xz`
3. Create the following 2 folders for the locally installed `npm` manager:
   `mkdir -p $DEPENDENCY_BASE/.npm $DEPENDENCY_BASE/node_modules/.bin`
4. Add the locally installed packages and `node.js` to the `PATH` so that they take precedence over the global ones:
   `export PATH="$DEPENDENCY_BASE/node_modules/.bin/:$DEPENDENCY_BASE/node/bin/:$PATH"`
5. Execute `node --version; npm --version` to ensure that the new versions are used now
6. Set the cache folder for `npm` to the one created in step 3, for which we have write permissions:
   `npm config set cache "$DEPENDENCY_BASE/.npm"`

Now every time a package has to be installed, the following command should be used:
`npm install --prefix $DEPENDENCY_BASE <package name>` [1]

It will install packages in the `$DEPENDENCY_BASE/node_modules/` folder, while the corresponding binaries will be linked in the `$DEPENDENCY_BASE/node_modules/.bin/` folder.

---

Apparently the same result can be achieved without installing a new version of `node.js` locally, but the installed `npm` version is rather old there, which is likely to lack certain features.

---

You can of course put commands 1 and 4 in the `$OPENSHIFT_HOMEDIR/app-root/repo/.openshift/action_hooks/pre_build` in order to use the command [1] for automatic deployment. Even better, instead of the command 1, set the global environment variable as described in the [Openshift documentation](https://developers.openshift.com/managing-your-applications/environment-variables.html#custom-variables).

If you want to use these commands interactively when connected via SSH, unfortunately the best way seems to be putting them in a bash script and running it manually. I couldn't find any working way to prepend the `$PATH` variable on login, since it is overwritten by the system afterwards.